# Is this a simple sentence?

Tags: verbs, sentence-structure

Is this a simple sentence- Every agreement of the unit is noted.

- Every agreement- subject
- of the unit - object
- is noted.- verb

Comment: It is passive, and 'of the unit' is not a direct object.  In a passive sentence, the 'patient' of the action becomes the subject, so there is no direct object.

Comment: so, of the unit is indirect object?

Comment: No, an indirect object uses the preposition 'to' or 'for', although that may be elided if the dative follows the verb.  'of the unit' is a restricting prepositional phrase -- it works like an adjective to narrow the search for the noun.  It is part of the subject noun phrase.

Answer (score 1):

The whole of "Every agreement of the unit" is a [noun phrase with a prepositional phrase as a dependent of "agreement"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase#Components_of_noun_phrases).